# GetCursorPos and Privileges

Tags: c++, c, winapi, mfc, mousemove

I have a method retrieving the cursor position and get the coordinate on a specific window using GetCursorPos() and ScreenToClient().
All It work perfectly except a strange thing.

**If the target window is run under administrator privilege and my application run under current user's privilege, I cant get the coordinate until my application window is over the target.**

Same thing happen if I run my appliction as administrator and the target run under current user.

Why ?

Edit :

The problem isnt getting the coordinate of the cursor, but getting the coordinate when the privilege of the window and my application are different.

**Problem found (not solved): The cause is "User Interface Privilege Isolation (UIPI)"**

Comment: A window doesn't have a cursor position.  A mouse does.  There's only one mouse.  If you want to map its screen position to a position that's relative from the window's client rectangle, like you do, then that's certainly possible.  But certainly no guarantee in your snippet that the mouse is even *inside* the window.

Comment: I expect `GetCursorPos()` is working fine, but the `ScreenToClient()` is failing as you don't have permission to access that window. Why do you want coordinates local to particular window? They're largely meaningless to anything outside that application.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the window's client area rectangle (`GetClientRect`) and subtract the client area's top left corner position from the mouse position, it's basically the same thing as `ScreenToClient()`

Code:

```
POINT screen_cursor_pos;
RECT client_rect;
int cursor_x,cursor_y;

GetCursorPos(&screen_cursor_pos);
GetClientRect(hwnd,&client_rect);

cursor_x=screen_cursor_pos.x-client_rect.left;
cursor_y=screen_cursor_pos.y-client_rect.top;
```

Comment: Just tried and it wont work, surely because of the User Interface Privilege Isolation (UIPI).

Comment: You might also try `GetWindowInfo` or `GetWindowRect`, or play by UIPI's rules and add a manifest to you application with `uiAccess="true"` , see this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb756929.aspx. I don't think there is a specific message to retrieve a window's position.